# JavaScript Type Conversion Table

Tags: javascript

I have a question about type conversions. Given the following table from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp)...

[image: table of conversions]

Why are the strings "0" and "000" converted to boolean true?

Comment: Any string that isn't `""` is true.

Comment: This ***has*** to be a duplicate.

Comment: @shotor: *That* has to be a duplicate as well. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - it is. but I can't find a single canonical SO answer for it.

Comment: I think the confusion here comes from sillyness like `"0" == false => true`, while `if ("0") { alert('!!') } => alerts`

Comment: Thank you all for support :)

Answer (score 1):

Because when you coerce a value to boolean in JavaScript, **any** non-blank string is `true`. Only blank strings are `false`.

Comment: Thanks very much ... its already clear for me ... Just one ... I cant understand why people in stackoverflow minuses my question (-) ... yes may be this is a duplicate , but i am a beginner  and i couldnt find the answer ...

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan: I can't say, I didn't downvote your question. But the most likely reason would be the first part of what it says on the downvote button: "...does not show any research effort..." The rules for JavaScript type coercion are **extremely** well-covered in lots of places on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of it is because both "0" and "000" are strings and not numbers.

Any string which is non-empty converted to boolean is going to be true.

Comment: Thanks very much ... its already clear for me ... Just one ... I cant understand why people in stackoverflow minuses my question (-) ... yes may be this is a duplicate , but i am a beginner  and i couldnt find the answer ...