# Why does as.numeric(1) == (3 | 4) evaluate to TRUE?

Tags: r

I wanted to make a simple comparison using `h == 1 | 2` where `h` could be an integer between 1 and 4. To my astonishment, it didn't work.

I could sort of understand why

> 1 == 2 | 4
>
> TRUE

and perhaps even why

> 1 == (2 | 4)
>
> TRUE

but why in the name of all that's reasonable and sane does

> as.numeric(1) == (2 | 4)

or

> 1L == (2 | 4)

or

> 3 == 2 | 4

evaluate to

> TRUE

???

How can I ask R to tell me whether `1 is equal to 2 or 4` and the answer will be `FALSE`?

Comment: you shoud use `1 %in% c(2,4)`

Comment: What do you expect `2|4` to evaluate to?

Comment: @HongOoi I would expect behaviour like in Julia or JavaScript, certainly not coercion from numeric to logical…

Comment: Please answer the question.   2|4 evaluates to TRUE even though ti's kind of a meaningless statement.    @dww is more along the lines of what you want.  Just testing 2|4   at the command line would have probably helped you understand the notation.

Comment: by the way, in Julia and python `1 == 2|4` is `false`, but  not for the reason you think: `|` is the bitwise or operator, so `2|4` evaluates to 6 ... Not really worth an answer of its own, but maybe worth someone including in an existing answer ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
1 == 2 | 4
```

[Operator precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) tells us it is equivalent to `(1 == 2) | 4`

`1 == 2` is `FALSE`, 4 is coerced to logical (because `|`is a logical operator),  `as.logical(4)` is `TRUE`, so you have `FALSE | TRUE`, that's `TRUE`

Indeed [coercion rules for logical operators](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html) (`?Logic`) tell us that:

> Numeric and complex vectors will be coerced to logical values, with
>   zero being false and all non-zero values being true.

---

```
3 == 2 | 4
```

Same thing

---

```
1 == (2 | 4)
```

`2 | 4` will be coerced to `TRUE | TRUE`, which is `TRUE`. Then `1 == TRUE` is coerced to `1 == 1` which is `TRUE`.

Indeed [coercion rules for comparison operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Comparison.html) (`?Comparison`) tell us that:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

---

```
as.numeric(1) == (2 | 4)
```

Same thing

---

```
1L == (2 | 4)
```

Same again

---

**1 is equal to 2 or 4**

is actually (1 is equal to 2) or (1 is equal to 4), which is:

```
(1==2)|(1==4)
```

which is

```
FALSE | FALSE
```

which is `FALSE`

Comment: Ahh, coercion… Thank you, I didn't realise something like `as.logical(4)` would be `TRUE`. I don't think that's reasonable at all.

Comment: It's like this in most languages, 0 is nothing, 1 or 4 or 100 is something, so it's `TRUE`, it's useful in many circumstances.

Comment: but `3 == TRUE` is FALSE, while `3 == 2 | 4` is TRUE

Comment: I think it would help a lot to parse the expression with `ast`: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html

Comment: Neither JavaScript nor Julia nor Python behave like this and I don't know much else. In any case, thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: but `bool(4)` is true so python _does_ behave the same way. `bool(0)` is false and `bool(-1)` is also true

Comment: Not `?logic`, rather `?Logic`

Comment: yes, and not `?comparison` but `?Comparison`, corrected, thanks

Comment: Note that the "safe and reliable way to test two objects for being exactly equal" is to use `identical()` (see `?identical`) so `1 == TRUE` is `TRUE` but `identical(1,TRUE)` is `FALSE`. This is a way to make sure no coercion occurs. So for your question `identical(1,2)|identical(1,4) = FALSE`

Comment: AFAIK Javascript also converts 0/Undefined/""/NaN to False and every other number, including Infinity, to True. So that also seems consistent with R's behaviour - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463109/javascript-type-conversion-table

Answer (score 4):

Running `2|4` evaluates to `TRUE`. That is why you obtain `TRUE` when comparing `1 == TRUE`. What you want to evaluate is `(1 == 2) | (1 == 4)`, which results in the desired `FALSE`.

Comment: see the other answer, you've got the operator precedence wrong

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to accept the more detailed answer but I appreciate yours too!

Answer (score 3):

The code that will deliver the expected answer to the implicit question in your first sentence is:

```
1 %in% 2:4
[1] FALSE

h=1
h %in% 1:2
[1] TRUE
```

The "==" operator does not implicitly generate a range (or a vector of alternatives) from a logical conjunction. It is considered a "Comparison"-operator and is  "generic" which will mean that methods can be different for different data-types. They are also vectorized (with the implicit recycling rules in force) so may return many values:

```
(1:2) == (1:4)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

And the `as.numeric()`-function applied to the value `1` will return exactly the input.

Further comment: Since your attempted use of "==" was really as an implicit set operation, you might want to review the help page for `?intersect`. There're also packages that handle more sophisticated set functions.

R's coercion can go back and forth between logical and numeric depending on how functions are defined:

```
sum( letters[1:10] %in% letters)
[1] 10

sum( letters[1:10] == letters)
[1] 10
Warning message:
In letters[1:10] == letters :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: I was looking for c(2, 4) rather than 2:4, but thanks, this is also useful.

Comment: Same difference, really. `1 %in% c(2,)` is likewise FALSE. Python's `or`-function handles numeric values in a bitwise binary fashion so `2 or 3` returns `2`. I would dispute any claim that this is more "intuitive" than what R returns. Both are useful in exactly the same setting... their use by someone who has taken the time to read the definitions of the operators and datatypes.